# HTML Show 5audio Player and get Media from db

Tags: php, mysql, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm designing a website for a church and the want to upload every sermon.
So I want to create a page, which shows the last 5 tracks with all information.
My idea is, to get the infos from a MySQL database with the file path from the track. 
Maybe you have a better solution, but I want get the track path with a little PHP code. Do my problem is,that I'm don't know how to bring this path from the PHP code in the  from the html. 
And I don't know how to get the highest primary key from the db-tabel

I hope you understand what I want. And ki hope also you can help me.

Best wishes

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Or read any tutorials about how to upload files, how to store info in mySQL using PHP and how to read info back from mySQL using PHP? This question is really too broad. You should make an attempt and then ask specific question(s) when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest primary key from the db-table try this:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```